# Difference between `get()` and `UQ()`

Tags: r, dplyr, rlang

I'm trying to use dplyr's `group_by()` for a variable called (`choice`) that changes depending on the input given to a Shiny application, and to do that I've been trying to use `rlang::UQ(choice)`. This doesn't work in the manner I'd expect, although it works with `get(choice)`. Here is a small example:

```
DF <- structure(list(Cd_AnoExecucao = c(2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 
2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L), Ds_Orgao = c("Instituto de Previdência Municipal de São Paulo", 
"Subprefeitura M´Boi Mirim", "Secretaria Municipal de Direitos Humanos e Cidadania", 
"Subprefeitura Perus", "Secretaria Municipal dos Negócios Jurídicos", 
"Subprefeitura Aricanduva/Formosa/Carrão", "Secretaria Municipal de Direitos Humanos e Cidadania ", 
"Companhia Metropolitana de Habitação de São Paulo", "Subprefeitura Parelheiros", 
"Subprefeitura Vila Prudente"), Jan_Real = c(0, 29945, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 212480, 0), Fev_Real = c(0, 0, 0, 37820.8, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 24571.26), Mar_Real = c(0, 0, 0, 36772.7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0), Abr_Real = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), Mai_Real = c(0, 
0, 0, 39783.2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), Jun_Real = c(0, 0, 0, 34966.4, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), Jul_Real = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), 
    Ago_Real = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), Set_Real = c(0, 
    0, 94600, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), Out_Real = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), Nov_Real = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0), Dez_Real = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)), .Names = c("Cd_AnoExecucao", 
"Ds_Orgao", "Jan_Real", "Fev_Real", "Mar_Real", "Abr_Real", "Mai_Real", 
"Jun_Real", "Jul_Real", "Ago_Real", "Set_Real", "Out_Real", "Nov_Real", 
"Dez_Real"), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"))
```

And the variable:

```
choice <- "Ds_Orgao"
```

Now the two ways that I'm trying:

```
> DF %>% group_by(UQ(choice)) %>% summarise(unique = unique(UQ(choice)))
# A tibble: 1 x 2
  `"Ds_Orgao"`   unique
         <chr>    <chr>
1     Ds_Orgao Ds_Orgao
```

And:

```
> DF %>% group_by(get(choice)) %>% summarise(unique = unique(get(choice)))
# A tibble: 10 x 2
                                           `get(choice)`                                                unique
                                                   <chr>                                                 <chr>
 1     Companhia Metropolitana de Habitação de São Paulo     Companhia Metropolitana de Habitação de São Paulo
 2       Instituto de Previdência Municipal de São Paulo       Instituto de Previdência Municipal de São Paulo
 3  Secretaria Municipal de Direitos Humanos e Cidadania  Secretaria Municipal de Direitos Humanos e Cidadania
 4 Secretaria Municipal de Direitos Humanos e Cidadania  Secretaria Municipal de Direitos Humanos e Cidadania 
 5           Secretaria Municipal dos Negócios Jurídicos           Secretaria Municipal dos Negócios Jurídicos
 6               Subprefeitura Aricanduva/Formosa/Carrão               Subprefeitura Aricanduva/Formosa/Carrão
 7                             Subprefeitura M´Boi Mirim                             Subprefeitura M´Boi Mirim
 8                             Subprefeitura Parelheiros                             Subprefeitura Parelheiros
 9                                   Subprefeitura Perus                                   Subprefeitura Perus
10                           Subprefeitura Vila Prudente                           Subprefeitura Vila Prudente
```

(I'm not actually after this exact result, I just wanted to show the difference.)

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You need `rlang::sym`.  See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43436900/how-to-make-shinys-inputvar-consumable-for-dplyrsummarise)

Comment: Yes, I do! Fantastic. If you want to write that up (one line haha) as an answer, I'll happily accept it. Thanks for the help!