# I can't use summarize (mean function) in shiny to plot bar graph

Tags: r, shiny

I tried to calculate the average of pedal length (or width) within in each species and then plot it in bar graph using the shinny app. But the mean function in summarize keeps giving me issues.

```
library(datasets)
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
data("iris")

# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
ui <- fluidPage(

    # Application title
    titlePanel("Analyze Iris table"),

    # Sidebar with a dropdown menu selection input for key meausre compoenent
    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
            selectInput("yInput", "Measuring element: ", 
                            colnames(iris), selected = colnames(iris)[2]), 
            selectInput('xInput', 'Grouper: ', 
                            colnames(iris), selected = colnames(iris)[5])
        ),

        # Show a plot of the generated distribution
        mainPanel(
           plotOutput("barPlot")
        )
    )
)
```

## Define server logic required to draw a histogram

```
server <- function(input, output) {

    by_xInput <- reactive({


        iris %>% 
        group_by(input$xInput) %>% 
        summarize(n = length(input$xInput), mean_y = mean(input$yInput))

        })

    output$barPlot <- renderPlot({
        # generate bins based on input$bins from ui.R
        ggplot(data = by_xInput(), aes(x = input$xInput, y = mean_y)) + 
            geom_bar(stat = 'identity')

        })

}
```

## Run the application

```
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: I thin your problem is related to the **names** of the variables in the IRIS. They have a **.**. Try removing it

Comment: I flagged this as a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43436900/5325862), and @YitongLi it seems you confirmed. Since then, someone else has reopened it. Which was your intention?

Comment: @camille I reopened it because it was only partially dupe.  There is also the `ggplot` `aes_string` which needs modification

Comment: @akrun I just wanted to check whether the OP wanted their closing to be overridden. An `aes_string` option would make a fine addition to the previous post, although it's soft-deprecated

Comment: @camille Your dupe tag would solve the first issue with `summarise` and it didn't had any `ggplot` component that needs to be fixed

Comment: @camile I agree with akrun that these two are not exactly the same. Before I posted my question, I was searching for hours but couldn't find anything to solve my problem. And I have seen the duplicate one you referenced. akrun was such an hero and helped me get this through! I'm new to programming and this community so I'm still learning to navigate the website. Thank you so much for your patience with me :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here, it is a string element, so convert to `sym`bol and evaluate (`!!`)

```
library(dplyr)
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
server <- function(input, output) {

    by_xInput <- reactive({


      iris %>% 
        group_by_at(input$xInput) %>% 
        # n() can replace the length
        # convert string to symbol and evaluate (!!)
        summarize(n = n(), mean_y = mean(!! rlang::sym(input$yInput)))


        })

    output$barPlot <- renderPlot({

        # as the input is a string, use `aes_string`
        ggplot(data = by_xInput(), aes_string(x = input$xInput, y = "mean_y")) + 
            geom_bar(stat = 'identity')

        })

}
```

-testing

```
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

-output

[image]

Comment: Thanks! The data are corrected now but the graph is still not right :(  I added !! rlang::sym() to aes(x = ...) since that one changes with the input, but got the error of can't find rlang

Comment: @YitongLi  Why is it not correct?  It is giving the output based on the input you provided.  Check `iris %>% group_by(Sepal.Width) %>% summarise(n = n(), mean_y = mean(Petal.Length)) %>% ggplot(., aes(x = Sepal.Width, y = mean_y)) + geom_bar(stat = 'identity')`

Comment: @YitongLi  Have you checked my updated code because I am using `aes_string` instead of `aes`.  Also, if you don't have package `rlang` installed, then `install.packages("rlang")`